# How to add a timeout for a websocket connect

Tags: python-3.x

I have some code as follows:

```
async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
   # Do my websocket thing..
```

I'd like to add a connection timeout so if the server is not available it doesn't hang. How can I do this?

I think it's adding an await to websockets.connect(), but everything I've tried isn't working..

Answer (score 0):

You can use asyncio's wait_for() like this:

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import TimeoutError as ConnectionTimeoutError
# whatever url is your websocket server
url = 'ws://localhost:9090'
# timeout in seconds
timeout = 10  
try:
    # make connection attempt
    connection = await asyncio.wait_for(websockets.connect(uri, timeout=2, close_timeout=2), timeout=3)
    # connection is a websockets instanse. So you can use send() or recv() 
    # methods
    data = await connection.recv()
except ConnectionTimeoutError as e:
    # handle error
    print('Error connecting.')
```

It will raise a `<class 'concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError'>` exception which can be caught with the `except ConnectionTimeoutError` block.

In python3.8 it raises a `TimeoutError` which can be caught with the `except asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError` block.

Or if you want to use your async construction you can do this:

```
async with (websockets.connect(uri, timeout=2, close_timeout=2) as websocket:
    # implement here your logic
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. From what I understand the timeout is actually a close timeout and not the initial connection timeout which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I corrected my answer. May be this solution can help you

Comment: Okay - that does work to catch not connecting.. but what should I do with the code I had in the async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket: block?  
I can't figure out how to get it to run now..

Comment: You can use both construction. I will correct my answer there will be wto ways

Comment: The first way does not allow me to use the with, so it would be the second way.. but this does not catch the timeout of not being able to connect to the uri..

Comment: Construction "async with" is a context that allows to you don't close the resources manually. So think about your resources. May be you will be able to close them manually

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing what Andrei suggested and used the try / except code, then followed it up with similar code as before, but added the close.

```
        try:
                # make connection attempt
                websocket = await asyncio.wait_for(websockets.connect(uri), timeout)
                print("\t\t SS> Connected")
        except:
                # handle error
                print('SS> Error connecting.')
                rtn = [None,None]
                return rtn
        else:
            print("\t SS> Connected " + uri)
            try:
                await websocket.send(json_start)
                print("\t SS> {json_start}")
            except:
                print("\t SS> ERROR: Unable to send {json_start}")

            # and yet more code..

            await websocket.close() 
            return rtn
```